# How to use colume name as variable in msaccess with php

Tags: php, variables

```
$att="select AttData.Rollno,AttData.Name,AttData.Year,AttData.sec,
        AttData.".$date." 
  from AttData where AttData.sec='".$sec."' 
    and AttData.dept='".$dept."' 
    and  AttData.year='".$year."' and AttData.".$date."='AB'  ";
```

I am trying to select absents data from AttData table with dynamic column value as date variable .

But i am getting following error :

> Warning: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Invalid use of '.', '!', or '()'. in query expression 'AttData.'02-07-2016'., SQL state 37000 in SQLExecDirect in C:\xampp\htdocs\sms\repotdaygen_allyear.php on line 325
>   select invalid37000

Please help me what is the error.

Comment: use `date_column_name` from the table instead of value `$date`

Answer (score 0):

If a string is enclosed in double-quotes ("), PHP will interpret the variables. So try this:

```
$att="select AttData.Rollno,AttData.Name,AttData.Year,AttData.sec,AttData.$date from AttData where AttData.sec='$sec' and AttData.dept='$dept' and AttData.year='$year' and AttData.$date='AB' ";
```

In addition, use braces to ensure PHP doesn't miss the variables when they are followed by other chars:

```
$att="select AttData.Rollno,AttData.Name,AttData.Year,AttData.sec,AttData.{$date} from AttData where AttData.sec='{$sec}' and AttData.dept='{$dept}' and AttData.year='{$year}' and AttData.{$date}='AB' ";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$att="select AttData.Rollno,AttData.Name,AttData.Year,AttData.sec,AttData.{$date} from AttData where AttData.sec='{$sec}' and AttData.dept='{$dept}' and AttData.year='{$year}' and AttData.{$date}='AB' ";
```

i hope it will be helpful

Comment: sir iam getting this error Warning: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Invalid use of '.', '!', or '()'. in query expression 'AttData.'02-07-2016'., SQL state 37000 in SQLExecDirect in C:\xampp\htdocs\sms\repotdaygen_allyear.php on line 325
select invalid37000

Comment: Sir i am use Ms access and php

Comment: Roll no : text
Regno: text
Name-: text
Dept: text
Sec: text
Year: text
Daysabsent: text
’02-07-2016: text

Comment: sir u have any itea

Comment: @Mohanaprakash : what is '$date'?maybe it's not match with your columns name.